# Why are HTML/Javascript buttons messing up my CSS drop down-menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

The buttons I'm trying to make are made so that they go a certain C.S.S. ID. "I put to much code in" before I tested it in my browser and instead of showing only when I hover over About Us, all the names appear right on the parent menu.

Specs:

- **Browser used to test:** Chrome

CSS & HTML:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,600,300);

*{
 padding : 0;
 margin : 0;
}

a.hlink:link {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}
a.hlink:visited {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}
a.hlink:hover {color : #ffffff; text-decoration : none;}
a.clink:link {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}
a.clink:visited {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}
a.clink:hover {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}

ul {list-style: none;padding: 0x;margin: 0px;width: 232px;height: 40px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;padding: 5px}
li ul {display: none;}
ul li a {display: block;background: #fff;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;white-space: nowrap;color: #000;}
ul li a:hover {background: #fff;}
li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute; width: 150px;}
li:hover li {float: none;}
li:hover a {background: #fff;}
li:hover li a:hover {background: #fff;}
#drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
#drop-nav:after {content: "";clear: both;display: table;}

body{
 background-image : url(' Images/IST Wizards2.png ');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center; 
 background-attachment : fixed;
 background-size : 100%;
 background-size : cover;
}
header{
 background-color : #ffffff;
 background-position: center; 
 background-attachment : fixed;
 background-size : cover;
 font-family : 'Open Sans', Sans-Serif;
 font-weight : 600;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #000000;
}
.buttons{
 font-family : 'Open Sans', Sans-Serif;
 font-weight : 600;
 border : 0;
 background : #ffffff;
 font-size : 12pt;
 outline: none;
}
.buttons:hover{
 cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
  <title>WELCOME!</title>
 </head>
 <header>
 <img src="Images/IST Logo.png" style="height : 30px; position : absolute; top : 5px; left : 5px;">
  <ul id="drop-nav">
  
    <li> <button class="buttons" onclick="document.getElementById('Home').scrollIntoView();">HOME</button></li>
    <li> <button class="buttons" onclick="document.getElementById('About Us').scrollIntoView();">ABOUT US
   <ul>
     <li> <button class="buttons"  onclick="document.getElementById('Anthony').scrollIntoView();">Anthony</button></li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Brandon').scrollIntoView();">Brandon</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Colyn').scrollIntoView();">Colyn</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Elijah').scrollIntoView();">Elijah</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Evan').scrollIntoView();">Evan</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Gabe').scrollIntoView();">Gabe</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Joel').scrollIntoView();">Joel</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Joe').scrollIntoView();">Joe</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Matt').scrollIntoView();">Matt</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Mike B.').scrollIntoView();">Mike B.</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Mike D.').scrollIntoView();">Mike D.</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Nate').scrollIntoView();">Nate</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Nic').scrollIntoView();">Nic</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Reese').scrollIntoView();">Reese</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Rhalene').scrollIntoView();">Rhalene</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Robert').scrollIntoView();">Robert</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Sagan').scrollIntoView();">Sagan</li>
     <li onclick="">Xavier</li>
   </ul>
    </li>
    <li onclick="document.getElementById('Contact').scrollIntoView();">CONTACT</li>
  </ul>
 </header>
 <body>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

P.S. If you feel ever so inclined to make the code more efficient, feel free to do so.

Comment: Can you please add image how it will look originally?

Comment: That's the thing I'm not sure what caused it, all the names after ABOUT US and before CONTACT are only supposed to show under the tab when you mouse over ABOUT US.

Comment: On second thought I could use the on-click events in the actual <li> tag and that would fix the drop-down problem and put buttons:hover or whatever to make the cursor seem like a pointer finger. Thanks for tying to help and sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: I would seriously consider using `<a>` tags referencing sections with an ID. E.g: `<li><a href="#Sagan">Sagan</a></li>`

Comment: I didn't know that worked like that thanks! @Jon P

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `</button>` closer tag and also your `<header>` was starting before `body` tag.

Please check below code snippet, Its working fine now :

Thanks

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,600,300);

*{
 padding : 0;
 margin : 0;
}

a.hlink:link {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}
a.hlink:visited {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}
a.hlink:hover {color : #ffffff; text-decoration : none;}
a.clink:link {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}
a.clink:visited {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}
a.clink:hover {color : #000000; text-decoration : none;}

ul {list-style: none;padding: 0x;margin: 0px;width: 232px;height: 40px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;padding: 5px}
li ul {display: none;}
ul li a {display: block;background: #fff;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;white-space: nowrap;color: #000;}
ul li a:hover {background: #fff;}
li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute; width: 150px;}
li:hover li {float: none;}
li:hover a {background: #fff;}
li:hover li a:hover {background: #fff;}
#drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
#drop-nav:after {content: "";clear: both;display: table;}

body{
 background-image : url(' Images/IST Wizards2.png ');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center; 
 background-attachment : fixed;
 background-size : 100%;
 background-size : cover;
}
header{
 background-color : #ffffff;
 background-position: center; 
 background-attachment : fixed;
 background-size : cover;
 font-family : 'Open Sans', Sans-Serif;
 font-weight : 600;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #000000;
}
.buttons{
 font-family : 'Open Sans', Sans-Serif;
 font-weight : 600;
 border : 0;
 background : #ffffff;
 font-size : 12pt;
 outline: none;
}
.buttons:hover{
 cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
  <title>WELCOME!</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <header>
 <img src="Images/IST Logo.png" style="height : 30px; position : absolute; top : 5px; left : 5px;">
  <ul id="drop-nav">
  
    <li> <button class="buttons" onclick="document.getElementById('Home').scrollIntoView();">HOME</button></li>
    <li> <button class="buttons" onclick="document.getElementById('About Us').scrollIntoView();">ABOUT US</button>
   <ul>
     <li> <button class="buttons"  onclick="document.getElementById('Anthony').scrollIntoView();">Anthony</button></li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Brandon').scrollIntoView();">Brandon</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Colyn').scrollIntoView();">Colyn</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Elijah').scrollIntoView();">Elijah</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Evan').scrollIntoView();">Evan</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Gabe').scrollIntoView();">Gabe</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Joel').scrollIntoView();">Joel</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Joe').scrollIntoView();">Joe</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Matt').scrollIntoView();">Matt</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Mike B.').scrollIntoView();">Mike B.</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Mike D.').scrollIntoView();">Mike D.</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Nate').scrollIntoView();">Nate</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Nic').scrollIntoView();">Nic</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Reese').scrollIntoView();">Reese</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Rhalene').scrollIntoView();">Rhalene</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Robert').scrollIntoView();">Robert</li>
     <li onclick="document.getElementById('Sagan').scrollIntoView();">Sagan</li>
     <li onclick="">Xavier</li>
   </ul>
    </li>
    <li onclick="document.getElementById('Contact').scrollIntoView();">CONTACT</li>
  </ul>
 </header>
 
  
 </body>
</html>
```